# How do I configure the lockscreen to use my PAM module in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, lock-screen, pam

In 14.04 I was able to do this by adding a line to `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` and my module is invoked for both login and the lock screen. In 16.04 it is only invoked at the login screen; the lock screen still only uses common-auth.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on 16.04.6 by editing the `/etc/pam.d/unity` file. Mine looks like this:

```
@include common-auth
auth required pam_u2f.so
auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```